Posets associated to covers
Given a covering $U_i$ of a topological space $X$ for $i$ in some indexing set $S$, there is a poset $P$ whose objects are subsets $I$ of $S$ so that $\cap_{I} U_i$ is non-empty and morphisms are inclusions. Then there is a functor $P \rightarrow Op(X)$, where the latter is the poset of opens in $X$, and the homotopy colimit $\lim (P\rightarrow Op(X)\rightarrow Spaces)$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$.
One natural question is what posets arise this way from a covering of a space $X$.
I suspect that any poset arises this way. Indeed, given any poset $P$, we can form its geometric realization $|P|$, which is the homotopy colimit $\lim(P \rightarrow * \rightarrow Spaces)$. Is there a natural covering of  $\lim(P \rightarrow * \rightarrow Spaces)$ whose associated poset is related to $P$?
More generally, given a functor $\phi: C \rightarrow Spaces$, is there a natural covering $U_i$ of the homotopy colimit $\lim(\phi: C \rightarrow Spaces)$, and if so, what is the poset associated to this cover? How does this poset relate to the category $C$? (which is not a poset). I would guess that it is the subdivision $sd C$, which I think should be a poset for arbitrary categories $C$.

It certainly isn’t true that any poset arises in the way you described in your first paragraph. For given a space $X$, consider that the poset $P$ defined in this paragraph has all meets (except possibly a terminal object). Given $(I_j)_{j \in J}$ where each $I_j \in P$ and $J$ is nonempty, $\bigcap\limits_{j \in J} I_j \in P$ is the meet of the $I_j$s. Consequently, any poset which does not have all these meets will not arise in this way.
For instance, consider the poset containing exactly two elements, and whose elements are incomparable. The two incomparable elements do not have a meet.

There seems to be a subtlety regarding sets of indices whose corresponding intersection is empty. The poset thus captures a small part of the combinatorial structure of the space.

@MarkSaving I'm confused about your last sentence. Can't I take X to be the disjoint union of two open subsets U_1 and U_2, and then cover X by U_1 and U_2? Then the poset associated to this covering will exactly have two incomparable elements. The issue is that the intersection of U_1 and U_2 is empty and so the corresponding poset does not have all meets. So I think I agree with Zhen Lin's comment.

@user39598 If we take $U_1, U_2$ nonempty and disjoint covering $X$, then $P$ will be a three-element set containing ${1}$, ${2}$, and $\emptyset$, not the 2-element poset with incomparable elements.
